# Time complexity analysis of this flip method

Tags: recursion, time-complexity

```
static void flip(int [] list, int start, int end){
    if(end - start > 0){
        flip(list, start + 1, end - 1);
        swap(list, end, start);
    }
}
```

Here, the time complexity of the swap method is O(1). Is the time complexity of the entire flip function O(n) or O(log n)? If not both, how do you analyze it?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned time complexity of `swap` is `O(1)`, so if we consider `T(n)` as the time complexity of `flip(list, x, x+n)`, then we have : `T(n) = T(n-2) + 1` which means `T(n)` is `O(n)` so time complexity of `flip` is `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I understand

Comment: @SeoJiWon glad that I could help. If it answered your question, please marked it as an answer, so that others could find it.